# asp.net core 2.2 identity custom storage provider for oracle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-identity, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have been looking but so far haven't been able to find an example that deal with core 2.2 Identity and creating a custom storage provider for oracle (which current will require ADO.net and CRUD methods as opposed to EF).

Can anyone point me to a good example or a good reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the exercise of customizing creating a custom storage provider for ASP.NET Core Identity so I could create a custom provider for IdentityServer4. I just created a minimal in memory provider. To use it with Oracle you just need to inject the Oracle data access and produce objects like the User class I have defined. The github project for my little experiment is here: https://github.com/glennsills/simpleidentity. Microsoft's documentation for a custom provider is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

I do not have experience working with Oracle. But after several searches, I found the following Providers:

1. For [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html), you can see samples [here](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/tree/master/samples/dotnet-core)
2. For [Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/), you can also see [the guide](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/EFCore-Database-First.html)

Comment: Thanks Ali, but these don't answer my question.  I fully understand how to use Oracle ODP.Net, ADO, and EF.  I am really looking for an example of a Identity Storage provider for core 2.2 Identity that uses CRUD as opposed to EF workings.